# for loop in TCL to read multiple files in a directory

Tags: foreach, tcl

I want to read multiple files about 30 files in a directory through for loop in
TCL and for each file I want to do something, e.g. load, run, inst.

I want to do some thing like:

```
set hosts [open "wcet_executable/*.exe"]
foreach host $hosts {
    load *.exe
    run
    inst
}
```

I am doing something wrong as I have no good experience in TCL, and the problem
is I want to do this in TCL.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is how you're trying to build the list of files.  `open` is not the correct command to use; that opens one file for read/write access.  To get a list of files in a directory, you need the [`glob`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/glob.htm) command.

In short:

```
set hosts [glob -directory "wcet_executable" -- "*.exe"]
```

will do what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks a lot the problem solved.

Here is my final tcl code:

```
set allexes [glob -directory "wcet_executable" -- "*.exe"]
foreach f $allexes {
   puts "$f"
    load "$f"
run
inst
```